# How to get Lightning date picker UI as in LDS design?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system, lightning-inputfield

I need the following Datepicker UI design as show in LDS base variant.
https://lightningdesignsystem.com/components/datepickers/#content

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_ui_inputDateTime.htm

i have tried with following code, but i'm getting normal datepicker only.

```
<lightning:input type="datetime-local" label="Birthday" name="datetime" />
```

How to make it work using lightning:input ?

Comment: SLDS is not currently supported with lightning:input for date picker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as @Himanshu commented - `lightning:input` does not support SLDS yet,

But [ui:inputDate](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_ui_inputDate.htm) does:

```
<ui:inputDate displayDatePicker="true"/>
```

[image]